# How to set different logout times for roles?

Tags: 7, sessions

I would like to define/set a log out time for different roles for my Drupal site.

Say for example if I set log out time for X role for 30 Minutes. The users under that role would be logged out in 30 Minutes from the time they logged in and also I would like to show notification to users for their remaining time for timeout.

How can I achieve that in Drupal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can achieve that using the [Automated Logout](https://www.drupal.org/project/autologout) module. combination of the [Javascript Timer](https://www.drupal.org/project/jstimer) module.

Using the Automated Logout module we can set different timeouts for user roles and using Javascript Timer we can display remaining session time (countdown timer) for a logged in user.

[Automated Logout](https://www.drupal.org/project/autologout)

> This module provides a site administrator the ability to log users out after a specified time of inactivity.
>
> It is highly customizable and includes "site policies" by role to enforce logout.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Different timeouts based on role
> - Disabling of timeouts based on role
> - Permission for users to set their own timeout
> - Includes some JS mechanisms to keep uses logged in even if multiple    tabs are open or if the user is working on a form for a long period
>   of time.
> - Includes developer hooks to allow users to remain logged in depending    on your own project specific requirements
> - Optional integration with [Javascript Timer](https://www.drupal.org/project/jstimer) Timer

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about this module. It is very interesting.